# Fill 2D array with 2 different numbers, but each number has to be placed next to an equal number

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random, multidimensional-array

I am trying to fill a 2d-array randomly with 0s and 1s. The condition is that each 1 has to be 'placed' right next to another 1 either vertically or horizontally, but not diagonally.

http://prntscr.com/8nzl19
On the screenshot you see 3 blocks of 1s. I want them to be 'connected' so that there is only one block of 1s.

Is there any algorithm or something to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by connected? I don't get your question exactly.

Comment: And what do you mean by `not diagonally`?? If I consider your example as 7x7 matrix, `1` at `(2,2)` and `1` at `(3,1)` are placed diagonally. Don't they?

Comment: Does each 0 have to be placed next to another 0 as well?

Comment: @vish4071 that's right. you got it.

Comment: @SpiderPig no. just each 1.

Comment: You start by filling the array with 0s and then you place 1s randomly but always next to an already existing one, except for the first 1 of course.

Comment: This needs a more formal description. And what does "randomly" mean? Do you want to sample uniformly from all possible boards? This might be very very hard to do. A theoretical approach is just: fill randomly + check if constraints are fulfilled. This is then some kind of Las-Vegas algorithm which might never stop for big boards!

Comment: As @sascha commented, without a formal description, your problem is *hard* to solve. With one assumption, I can provide a soution which I'll add as answer (if that helps)

Comment: This question is by far too unclear. Please clarify: do you want to simply generate a random distribution of 0s and 1s matching the above constraints or convert something like the given matrix to match the constraints?

Answer (score -1):

Since a trivial way would be filling whole matrix with 1's, I assume you want  minimum number of 0's turned to 1's.

Here is an approach that you can use:

- Find all the components of 1's in the matrix. (Give an identifier to them, lets call those in example as A,B,C)
- Create a copy of the matrix.
- Select A. Do BFS from all "outpoints" of A (surrounded by at least one `0`) to other connected components (B,C). (BFS for the shortest paths, of course)
- Now in the original matrix, mark these points with (say) 2's.
- Repeat above 2 steps with B and C as well. You can fill initial matrix with different path-identifiers if you want. (3 for B, 4 for C etc.)

Now, consider connected 1's as nodes and 2's, 3's etc. in graph as edges. The edge weight will (obviously) be the number of 2's, 3's etc. from one node to other. You can now form MST of this graph using Prims or Kruskals algo.

For a (n * n) matrix with `k` connected components of 1's, this algorithm takes O(k * n * n) + O(k * k) complexity.

Comment: What? Silent downvotes on answer mean nothing. If you ever downvote any answer, tell why (unless obvious).